# Kernel.php doesn't exist Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm following one tutorial while learning laravel but currently I've got this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class App\Http\Kernel does not exist in /var/www/html/cms/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:734

The class **does exist** in app/Http/Kernel.php.

Those are permissions of the file

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ivan www-data 1537 nov 26  2016 Kernel.php
```

Those are permission on whole directory files

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivan www-data    567 nov 26  2016 server.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivan www-data   1918 nov 26  2016 readme.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivan www-data   1026 nov 26  2016 phpunit.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivan www-data    212 nov 26  2016 package.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivan www-data    503 nov 26  2016 gulpfile.js
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivan www-data   1395 nov 26  2016 composer.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivan www-data   1646 nov 26  2016 artisan
drwxr-x---  2 ivan www-data   4096 jan 19 20:06 tests
drwxrwxrwx  5 ivan www-data   4096 jan 19 20:06 storage
drwxr-x---  5 ivan www-data   4096 jan 19 20:06 resources
drwxr-x---  7 ivan www-data   4096 jan 19 20:06 public
drwxr-x---  5 ivan www-data   4096 jan 19 20:06 database
drwxr-x--- 11 ivan www-data   4096 jan 19 20:06 app
-rw-rw-r--  1 ivan www-data 127324 jun  2 15:27 composer.lock
drwxr-x---  2 ivan www-data   4096 jun  2 15:29 config
drwxr-x---  3 ivan www-data   4096 jun  2 15:44 bootstrap
drwxr-xr-x 33 ivan www-data   4096 jun  2 15:48 vendor
```

When I run in my terminal `php artisan serve` and tried to load the site on `http://localhost:8000` site is running.

What can be the problem here?

Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
      ....
```

Update: Kernel.php from console/

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
```

Update: `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "graham-campbell/markdown": "^6.1",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.2",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Update:

```
>>> new App\Http\Kernel()
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel::__construct() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application, none given on line 1
>>> App\Http\Kernel()
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function App\Http\Kernel() in eval()'d code on line 1
```

Comment: Show the first 5 lines of `Kernel.php`. Is the namespace correct?

Comment: Updated with first lines of Kernel.php. They seems okay to me

Comment: Updated question again.

Comment: So the site runs with `php artisan serve` but not in apache?

Comment: Updated `composer.json` on question. Yes, site is running with `php artisan serve` but not on apache

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` to regenerate the autoload files.  Not sure what tutorial you followed, but what exactly were your steps?  Installation of Laravel is very straight forward and documented on their site, not sure if you should be following a third party tutorial for an install.

Comment: I've tried `composer dump-autoload`, `composer update`, `php artisan cache:clear`. I just downloaded whole project and changed in `.env` file the credentials for database. Also changed permissions of `bootstrap and storage` to be able laravel to write in storage. Basically everything was like is in official Laravel documentation.

Comment: Does `php artisan tinker` fail as well?

Comment: @Devon, no. I've got it `Psy Shell v0.7.2 (PHP 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 — cli) by Justin Hileman` when I run the command

Comment: So try running `new App\Http\Kernel()`, see what happens, if it still fails, try including the file app/Http/Kernel.php explicitly and try again, try creating a new class in app/Http to test out the namespace.  This would work out of box if you installed using the Laravel instructions so something must have went wrong

Comment: Sorry, do you mean to run new kernel.php in tinker? `So try running new App\Http\Kernel()`?

Comment: Yes, tinker (psysh) is a PHP shell.

Comment: @Devon, I'm not sure If i'm doing this correctly but please check my updated question

Comment: The first line shows the class was found, so the problem isn't with your namespaces or composer.